# GameObject cant find findgameobjectwithtag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I am a bit confused as to why this is, so basically Im trying to get it to where the camera follows the player without moving left and right with him.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMotor : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform lookAt;
    private Vector3 startOffset;
    private Vector3 moveVector; 

    void Start () {
        GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        moveVector = lookAt.position + startOffset;

        //X
        moveVector.x = 0; //center of track
        //Y[image][1]
        moveVector.y = Mathf.Clamp(moveVector.y,3,5);// for ramps/stairs
            transform.position = moveVector;

    }
}
```

Comment: Tags and searching for objects isn't great coding practice. Your class should have a reference to the Player object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If you are looking for an object in your scene, then use this simple script;

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour {


    private Transform lookAt;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        lookAt.Find("The Object That You are Looking For");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `GameObject.FindWithTag`
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

Even so,

```
GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
```

does nothing. (Nothing usefull atleast)

`lookAt` is never assigned, so im guessing what you want to do is

```
lookAt = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
```

Comment: Ok so Ive added that in but I still get the error message for GameObject cant find FindGameObjectWithTag,

Comment: Isnt it just GameObject.FindWithTag?

Comment: Nah it only says GameObject.Equals and Reference Equals in my suggesteds, if you have a solution for this can you break it down a bit? Im very new to c# lol

Comment: GameObject.FindWithTag is correct https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html

Comment: Yeah its supposed to but GameObject isnt accessing anything :/

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you see it in both Unity Console and your IDE (Mono/Visual Studio)?

Comment: error CS0117 GameObject does not contain a definition for 'FindWithTag'

Comment: both console and ide

Comment: @sunsetfox; that's weird. It is the only error that appears in the console?

Comment: it also doesnt have a definition for lookat but besides that thats about it.

Comment: is there another way I could access the player without using gameobject?

Comment: Unless you're accessing your Player without a MonoBehaviour like in a static class, no. GameObject is the best way to do it. There should be a reference to ```GameObject.FindWithTag```. More than likely, you have another build problem in your script if you can't see that static method.